# How can I summarize the values of a raster to make a clear legend?

Tags: qgis, raster, print-composer, legend, aster

[image]

I produced a relief map out of a ASTER Satellite Picture by using a colour ramp (Symbology -> band rendering). I want to make a map out of that in the Print Composer but the Legend is very confusing with all that values. I'd like to have a legend which shows values like 0-100 m = darkgreen, 101-200 m = green, ..., 1200-1300 = dark red.

Comment: What does your legend look like now, and how do you want it to look? Please [edit] your question, with pictures if possible.